# How to validate multiple values without if condition swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement

Is that a possible way to do in conditional statements

```
if let offer = self.offer_visitor_["Offer"],  let video = self.offer_visitor_["VideoReward"],  let bday = self.offer_visitor_["BirthdayReward"],let Promotional = self.offer_visitor_["promotional"]{
            
            if !offer.isEmpty && !video.isEmpty && !bday.isEmpty && !Promotional.isEmpty{
                return 4
            }else if !offer.isEmpty && !bday.isEmpty && !video.isEmpty {
                return 3
            }else if !offer.isEmpty && !video.isEmpty && !Promotional.isEmpty {
                return 3
            }else if !offer.isEmpty && !bday.isEmpty && !Promotional.isEmpty {
                return 3
            }else if !video.isEmpty && !bday.isEmpty && !Promotional.isEmpty {
                return 3
            }else if !offer.isEmpty && !video.isEmpty {
                return 2
            }else if !offer.isEmpty && !bday.isEmpty {
                return 2
            }else if !offer.isEmpty && !Promotional.isEmpty{
                return 2
            }else if !video.isEmpty && !bday.isEmpty {
                return 2
            }else if !video.isEmpty && !Promotional.isEmpty {
                return 2
            }else if !bday.isEmpty && !Promotional.isEmpty {
                return 2
            }else if !offer.isEmpty {
                return 1
            }else if !video.isEmpty {
                return 1
            }else if !bday.isEmpty {
                return 1
            }else if !Promotional.isEmpty {
                return 1
            }else{
                UIView.transition(with: self.noHistory_Label!,
                                  duration: 0.35,
                                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                                  animations: { [weak self] in
                                        self?.noHistory_Label?.text = UserDefaults.language == "ar" ? ArabicLanguageFile.NoOffers : EnglishLanguageFile.NoOffers
                                  }, completion: nil)
                return 0
            }
        }else{
            UIView.transition(with: self.noHistory_Label!,
                              duration: 1,
                              options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                              animations: { [weak self] in
                                self?.noHistory_Label?.text = UserDefaults.language == "ar" ? ArabicLanguageFile.NoOffers : EnglishLanguageFile.NoOffers
                }, completion: nil)
            return 0
        }
```

if dynamic values is that way to use
something like that

let count = [arrayData1["Available Offers"]?.count != 0, arrayData1["Redeemtion Offers"]?.count != 0, arrayData1["Redeemtion Vouchers"]?.count != 0, self.arrayData1["Available Vouchers"]?.count != 0].filter { $0 == true }.count

map
filter

Thanks

Comment: What are all these magic numbers being returned?

Comment: What do you want to count ?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understand it, this is just a really complex way of counting how many of these 4 things is not empty. Seems easy enough:

```
let emptyObjectCount = [offer, video, bday, promotional]
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    .count
```

Though these variable names make no sense, you should improve them.

Comment: Maybe counting **NOT !** empty collections  ‍♂️